# Square with diagonal in Pascal

Tags: pascal, turbo-pascal

I have written an application which will write square with diagonal (from left side) - output:

```
+ * * * *
* + * * *
* * + * *
* * * + *
* * * * +
```

Code for first application:

```
PROGRAM cycle4;
USES  CRT;
VAR a,r,s:INTEGER;
BEGIN
  CLRSCR;    
  WRITE (‘Enter the number of lines :‘) ;
  READLN(a);
  FOR r:= 1 TO  a DO
  BEGIN
    FOR s:=1 TO a  DO 
      IF r =  s THEN WRITE(‘+‘) 
      ELSE WRITE(‘*‘)  ;
      WRITELN;
  END;
  READLN;
END.
```

And now I have to create an application which will write square with diagonal (from right side) - output:

```
* * * * +
* * * + *
* * + * *
* + * * *
+ * * * *
```

But I don't know how can I write it. Can you help me?

Thanks :)

Comment: Could you post your code of the first application?

Comment: @demonplus i have posted it

Comment: Are you sure that you wrote the first code your self? Or did your teacher give it to you and asked if you could alter it? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line of code which defines the position of + sign is that:

```
IF r =  s THEN WRITE(‘+‘)
```

and this is the only line you need to change:

```
IF r + s =  a + 1 THEN WRITE(‘+‘)
```

I think this should work, check with Pascal compiler, haven't used it for about 10 years :)